# Fredholm theory on Fr\'echet spaces

Tags: operator-theory, fa.functional-analysis

Dear everybody,

In my study of the classial Fredholm theory on Banach spaces, I am interested in the corresponding Fredholm theory on Fr\'echet spaces. But it seems to me that there is
little research results in this aspect.

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be Fr\'echet spaces. An operator $T \in L(X,Y)$
is said to be upper (resp. lower) semi-Fredholm, if its kernel space
$\mathrm{ker}(T)$ is finite dimensional and its range space $R(T)$ is closed
in $Y$. In this case, the index of $T$ is defined as
$\mathrm{ind}(T)=\dim \mathrm{ker}(T) - \dim Y/R(T)$.

Now, one of my question is:

Suppose that $T \in L(X,Y)$ and $S \in L(Y,Z)$ are upper
semi-Fredholm, $ST$ is upper semi-Fredholm and $\mathrm{ind}(ST)=
\mathrm{ind}(S)+\mathrm{ind}(T)$? (It holds in Banach spaces case)

If you have any opinions to this question or this topic, please communicate with me. 
Thanks!

Comment: I fixed some latex (makebox doesn't seem to work here).  But you might clarify your question a little bit.  I see two ways of interpreting it:  1)  You are asking whether $ST$ is upper semi-Fredholm if $S$ and $T$ are, and whether the index of the product is the sum of the indices.  OR 2) You are assuming that $S$, $T$, and $ST$ are upper semi-Fredholm, and you are only asking about the property of the index.  (I think you are asking question 1, but it's not clear as written.)

Answer (score 2):

This book: Spectral Theory of Linear Differential Operators and Comparison Algebras
 By Heinz Otto Cordes (mostly available on google books)

Discusses this, as does the earlier:

Einige Klassen singularen Gleichungen, by S. Prössdorf, Akademie-Verlag,
Berlin; Mathematische Reihe, Band 46, Birkhâuser, Verlag, Basel and
Stuttgart, 1974, 353 pp.